# 1 to Many join for SQL View where joined table may have 0 records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have been tasked with creating a view that needs to bring in up to 10 records from another table. Problem is this table may have 0, 5, 10, or more corresponding records.

Here is the very simplified design to only include what is relevant

```
    SalesOrderTable       OutsideSalesRepTable     SalesRepTable
    OrderID               BranchID                 SalesRepID
    CustID                CustID                   SalesRepName
    BranchID              SalesRepID
```

The first join needs to be between SalesOrderTable and OutsideSalesRepTable on BranchID & CustID
The second join needs to be between OutsideSalesRepTable and SalesRepTable on SalesRepID

The view will need to have columns listed as OutsideSalesRep1, OutsideSalesRep2, ... OutsideSalesRep10 and filled with the SalesRepName. I have no control over the design of this database. I would have much rather seen 10 fields dedicated to SalesRepIDs in the customer table and just used left joins.

If only 3 OutsideSalesReps exsit for the branch/customer than OutsideSalesRep4-10 should be null

This is the only part of the 165 column / 35+ table view I wasn't able to figure out.

Any help would be sincerely appreciated.

PS I'm semi-fresh to TSQL. Only been using it about 6 months.

EDIT: I linked to an image that shows a sample of the source data to assist (I hope) explain what I'm looking for.
the Pivot Table needs to show

```
    SONum OutsideRep1 OutsideRep2 OutsideRep3 ..... Outside Rep10
    5819  59          69          70          null  null     
    5821  59          70          null        null  null
```

http://www.bayernsupport.com/SQL.png

Comment: you need a [pivot query](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), since you're trying to convert a single column in the salesrep table into multiple columns in the query results.

Comment: So i've tried this approach several different ways, and it's likely my ignorance, but i cannot get a query to Pivot the way i need it to.

I can get it to Pivot IF i specify the SalesRepName or ID  in the "IN" clause of the Pivot, but I'm not going to know what those values are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it working with the assistance of a friend. It did require a pivot, but it also required an interesting query as the source, bear in mind the field names below don't exactly match, but the structure and end result was dead on.

SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT so.OrderID, 
            so.OrderName, 
            sr.SalesRepName,
            'SalesRep_'+CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY OrderName ORDER BY SalesRepName) AS VARCHAR(30)) rn
    FROM @SalesOrderTable so 
    JOIN @OutsideSalesRepTable osp ON so.BranchID = osp.BranchID and so.CustID=osp.CustID
    JOIN @SalesRepTable sr ON osp.SalesRepID = sr.SalesRepID

) src
PIVOT
(
      MAX(SalesRepName)
      FOR rn in (SalesRep_1, SalesRep_2, SalesRep_3,SalesRep_4, SalesRep_5,
      SalesRep_6,SalesRep_7,SalesRep_8,SalesRep_9,SalesRep_10)
) piv

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to join your tables with an `outer join` (ie: `left join` or `right join`)  (to allow for joins where there are no results) and to use a `pivot` to create columns from rows.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx